# Route to controller in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8, laravel-controller

I'm working with Laravel 8 and when I write the route to the `__invoke` controller like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController;

Route::get('/portfolio', 'PortfolioController')->name('portfolio');
```

It shows this error:

> Invalid route action: [PortfolioController]. `PortfolioController` is not invokable

So it only works like this:

```
Route::get('/portfolio', [PortfolioController::class, '__invoke'])->name('portfolio');;
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because it should find the `__invoke` which is the only one in `PortfolioController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PortfolioController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {

      $portfolio = [

      ['title' => 'Project #1'],
      ['title' => 'Project #2'],
      ['title' => 'Project #3'],
      ['title' => 'Project #4'],

      ];

      return view('portfolio',compact('portfolio'));
    }
}
```

Is Laravel 8 ignoring the `__invoke` attribute???

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Do it like so:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController;

Route::get('/portfolio', PortfolioController::class)->name('portfolio');
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

#### Explanation

Before Laravel 8, routes were namespaced in `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```php
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

// ...

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace) // <----
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

So, when you defined routes, like in your example:

```php
Route::get('/portfolio', 'PortfolioController')->name('portfolio');
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `PortfolioController` string was namespaced with `App\Http\Controllers`.

However, since Laravel 8 this behaviour has been modified. From the [v8 release note](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases):

> In Laravel 8.x, this property is `null` by default. This means that no
> automatic namespace prefixing will be done by Laravel. Therefore, in
> new Laravel 8.x applications, controller route definitions should be
> defined using standard PHP callable syntax:
>
> ```php
> use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
>
> Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
> ```

Now, for the particular case you mentioned, `__invoke()` methods, this is how you should handle them [according to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#single-action-controllers):

> When registering routes for single action controllers, you do not need
> to specify a method:
>
> ```php
> use App\Http\Controllers\ShowProfile;
>
> Route::get('user/{id}', ShowProfile::class);
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing explanation 

Comment: Or you can use like this as well if you don't want to import all controller in the route file


`$router->group([ 'namespace' => '\App\Http\Controllers'], function ($router) {
  $router->get('portfolio', [
        'as' => 'portfolio',
        'uses' => 'PortfolioController::class',
    ]);
`
});

Answer (score 0):

another use , you can  use the full path

```php
Route::get('/portfolio', 'App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController')->name('portfolio');
```

or call a specific method

```php
Route::get('/portfolio', 'App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController@foo')->name('portfolio')
```