# Target class [ProductController] does not exist error in laravel 8.The way route is written is different

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to laravel and currently referring a tutorial to create a cart.The tutorial he is using laravel 5 but im using laravel 8.

i have a my shop products in this path **resources\views\flowers\shop.blade.php**

In route i used (routes\web.php)

```
Route::get('/shop',[
'uses'=>'ProductController@getIndex',
'as'=>'product.shop'    
]);
```

In app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return view('flowers.shop');
}
```

In app\Models\Product.php

```
{
protected $fillable = ['imagepath','card-title','card-text','card-price'];
}
```

Please help me to create this correctly.Thank you

Comment: See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188823/9025586

Comment: @MasoodKhan Thank you very much