# Views showing welcome.blade.php or 404 not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

**web.php**

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', PagesController::class, 'index');
Route::get('/test', PagesController::class, 'test');
```

**PagesController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('invoices.index');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return view('invoices.test');
    }
}
```

**Folder structure**

```
views
  invoices
    index.blade.php
    test.blade.php
  layouts
    app.blade.php
  welcome.blade.php
```

**Problem**

When I run `php artisan serve` and go to `localhost:8000` I see the welcome.blade.php template and when I go to localhost:8000/test I get 404 not found.

I tried the following commands with no success.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: because you made the `/test` route post request and you seem you want to access it with `get` request

Comment: You have to use `get` method for `test`

Comment: That was my bad, I tried to test it with post, but doesn't work, just like with get request. I edited the original code now.

Comment: And that also doesn't explain why / returns the welcome.blade.php since it should return the invoices.index.blade.php I tried to make a new project to see if there will be any difference, still the same.

Comment: it looks that there is another project opens in this port try to run your current project in another port like this `php artisan --port=8080`

Comment: Just tried php artisan serve --port=8080 and get same result, even tried php artisan serve --port=8070 just to be sure without success.

Comment: could you rewrite your route defenition like this one `Route::get('/test', [PagesController::class, 'test']);`

Comment: i suggest you to restart your pc then run `php artisan serve` then check it

Comment: I tried that as well, can something still run after PC restart? Also, in previous project I had storage and I just see that on fresh install, I now have storage folder as well, but I don't think that should be there on fresh installation right?

Answer (score 0):

Check your route definition.
It should be something like:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

or

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
```

You can also try:

```
Route::view('/', 'invoices.index');
```

Comment: Just tried both solutions, result is the same, / shows me the welcome.blade.php view and /test shows 404 | NOT FOUND

Comment: Try `Route::view('/', 'invoices.index')`  as well

Comment: Tried, still showing the welcome.blade.php template.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;

Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/test', [PagesController::class, 'test']);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64187141/route-to-controller-in-laravel-8)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that since someone else suggested that syntax as well, still the same problem. Might be something wrong with my installation since I never used linux before, but I followed step by step ubuntu and laravel installation and it worked for that person.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8 Route structure change

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
```

If you want to write previous structure, just add route namespace in `Providers -> RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)        // make sure this is present in your code
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

I hope it will be work!